# Divs won't work

Tags: html, css

I just want to make everything in the 'wrapper' stretch out to fit the wrapper, but everything is being annoying and staying a fixed height??

So I wanted the 'sidebar' and the 'inside' of the 'content' area to be the same height all of the time, and i also want the 'content' to stretch to fit the 'wrapper' at all time, while having a 'header', 'nav', and 'footer'. but nothing I try seems to work. I had it at one point but lost the code and forgot what I did.. help? :c

also I was playing around to see what would happen by changing the 'wrapper's min-height, that's why it is so low.

OKAY. **to specify**: for one, I want the 'wrapper' to encapsulate everything inside of it and always increase its height when one of the children increase their height, like with the 'inside' div is filled with text and increases the height of the 'content'
**In addition**, I also want the 'sidebar' and 'inside' to keep the same height, aka why they have a height of 100% or top; 0 bottom; 0 w/e i have on here.

**Html**:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 180px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
#inside {
  width: 779px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: orange;
  float: right;
}
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  background-color: pink;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="header">
    hi
  </div>

  <div id="nav">
    hi
  </div>

  <div id="content">

    <div id="sidebar">
      sidebar stuff
    </div>

    <div id="inside">
      inside stuff
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    hi
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: "but everything is being annoying and staying a fixed height??" That's funny

Comment: You would need to ask a question to get any kind of answer.

Comment: i am tho, I want to know how to make the wrapper increase its height whenever the content or anything inside of it increases its height. I just want the content to fill in the wrapper and for the sidebar and inside to be the same height at all times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, you're looking for same height columns.

Check these two links:

http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Comment: awh thanks c: but I figured it out, I just set the wrapper's position to absolute and changed a few other things and it works the way i want it to~~ thanks everyone hgjkdfs